# Is it possible to sort the order in which columns are returned in a mysql SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

**Imagine two questions from an online survey:**

1. Do you like apples?

> Result stored in mysql db column "q1" as **1** for Yes or **0** for No

2. Do you like oranges?

> Result stored in mysql db column "q2" as **1** for Yes or **0** for No

**Imagine the following SELECT statement:**

```
SELECT SUM(q1) AS q1Sum, SUM(q2) AS q2Sum FROM myTable
```

Assume q1Sum=10 and q2Sum=12.  The current SELECT statement would return:

```
+-------+-------+
| q1Sum | q2Sum |
+-------+-------+
|   10  |   12  |
+-------+-------+
```

**But** is it possible to return a different column order so that the greatest SUM is always the first column returned without changing the list order in the SELECT statement?

```
SELECT SUM(q1) AS q1Sum, SUM(q2) AS q2Sum FROM myTable << something else >>

+-------+-------+
| q2Sum | q1Sum |
+-------+-------+
|   12  |   10  |
+-------+-------+
```

If q1Sum becomes greater than q2Sum the column order returned would revert to the original order.

**Why am I asking this question?**

1. I have inherited a large table of multiple columns from a survey similar to above with Yes=1 and No=0 responses to multiple questions.  I assume the right way to do this is to create variables that hold the SUM values and insert them into temp table rows and then select/sort returned rows.  However, this doesn't really answer the question of 'is it possible to sort returned columns' and I'm not even sure my assumption is correct on the 'right way to do this'...
2. While I know how to sort the results once returned regardless of order (using php in my case), I was curious if there was a way to automatically sort the returned columns in mysql so that the highest value is always the first column and the SUM-ed results in the remaining columns decrease numerically for the remaining columns returned.
3. *Curious if there is an elegant answer.*  While it is easy to sort ROWS returned in mysql using ORDER BY, I have not seen an example of how to sort COLS of a single returned row of multiple SUM-ed values as articulated above.  Imagine 10 questions above instead of 2.  I am assuming this is not possible but hope someone can prove me wrong...in a nice way.

Comment: "No". *The shape (resulting columns) of a query is fixed.* The 'correct' solution, IMOHO, would be to normalize the data (via design or previous query result) - such that questions become *rows* - before operating on it. When done as part of a query this is also known as an 'UNPIVOT'; it does not necessarily require a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(q1) > SUM(q2) THEN SUM(q1) ELSE SUM(q2) END AS q1Sum,
   CASE WHEN SUM(q1) > SUM(q2) THEN SUM(q2) ELSE SUM(q1) END AS q2Sum 
FROM myTable
```

Actually this would mislabel the columns -- you cannot alter the name of the column without using `dynamic sql`.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks @user2864740 and @sgeddes for your prompt replies.*

> **SURVEY SAYS:**  It is NOT possible to sort returned columns in a SELECT statement using mysql without using dynamic sql.

The solution I came up with uses a temporary table and is similar to the example below.  While perhaps less than ideal, it answered the mail for what I needed. Curious if there is a better way to do the same thing or if I messed anything else up below.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS orderedSums;
SET @q1Sum = (SELECT SUM(q1) FROM myTable);
SET @q2Sum = (SELECT SUM(q2) FROM myTable);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE orderedSums (
    qNum VARCHAR(5),
    qSum INT
);

INSERT INTO orderedSums
    VALUES ('q1Sum', @q1Sum),('q2Sum', @q2Sum);

SELECT qNum, qSum
    FROM orderedSums
    ORDER BY qSum DESC;
```

Returns multiple rows of SUMs sorted in descending order from myTable.

Comment: Please consider using an unpivot. Then you can do it in a single query without temp tables. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table.

Comment: An equivalent result can be achieved in a single query (no need for a temporary table) `SELECT 'q1Sum' AS qNum, SUM(q1) AS qSum FROM myTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'q2Sum', SUM(q2) FROM myTable
    ORDER BY 2 DESC`

Comment: Thanks @siride. It seems this brings up the question of efficiency with multiple rows vs. multiple cols [(ref link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379083/more-efficient-to-have-more-columns-or-more-rows). In my case, I'm creating a simple dashboard of SUM totals for a very limited user base over a limited time. Probably not worth UNPIVOT but very useful link for future reference.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593. This brings up question of temp tables vs. union [(ref link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635615/sql-server-are-temp-tables-or-unions-better). Seems best to use UNION ALL. For multiple questions, UNION ALL's can be divided by parentheses: `(SELECT 'q1Sum' AS qNUM, SUM(q1) AS qSUM FROM myTable) UNION ALL (next q) UNION ALL (next q)...`

Comment: **Temp Table** approach:  `1.24s`  |  **UNION ALL** approach:  `93.8ms`

Comment: There's overhead in creating/populating/querying/dropping a temporary table. It's more work. Running the `UNION ALL` is going to be more efficient... that does the work you need done, without the unnecessary overhead. In my example UNION ALL query, parens can be wrapped around the SELECT statements, but it's not necessary, in this example,