# Rearranging column order in SELECT statement on MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, c, mysql-connector

I'm using the MySql C API and doing various queries I found it very inconvenient to go check the query each time to see the column ordering. Moreover, this approach is very prone to errors in case of a query edit.

**Is there anything I can do to assign by query each column ordinal?**

If not, is there a more convenient way to retrieve results via the C API? (currently using `mysql_fetch_row` and accessing the column id with the subscript operator).

Please not that I read the similar question [Is it possible to sort the order in which columns are returned in a mysql SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583349/is-it-possible-to-sort-the-order-in-which-columns-are-returned-in-a-mysql-select), but I found it different from my case as I need to assign an arbitrary number of column ordinals.

**Edit:**

**Current situation**

query: `SELECT A.a, A.b, A.c FROM tbl1 A INNER JOIN tbl2 B ON B.id = A.B_id`

c code:

```
...
MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
unsigned long *lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
...
int field1 = atoi(row[0]);
memcpy(row[1], field2, lengths[1]); 
..continue for each row..
```

**Desired situation**

query: `SELECT A.a ORDINAL 1, A.b ORDINAL 2, A.c ORDINAL 3 FROM tbl1 A INNER JOIN tbl2 B ON B.id = A.B_id`

c code: same as above.

Where `ORDINAL` statements are pseudo-SQL statements that would allow the returned columns to be ordered at wish.

Comment: Who voted for *close* could and should explain why he/she did so and how to improve the question.

Comment: A better idea of what you are trying to achieve may help. Maybe, you could use the mysql_fetch_fields function to associate column name with column number.

Comment: No, there isn't. The order is as specified in the `SELECT <here>` part of the query. If no order is specified in the query then you can assume it's arbitrary (although it's probably the create order).

Comment: @PaulF: I just edited the question as per your suggestion. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Can't you just create a list of constants & use those - assign them at the point where you create the query string & modify if you update the query. e.g const int col_Aa=0; const int col_Ab=1; ....... int field1 = atoi(row[col_Aa]); memcpy(row[col_Ab], field2, lengths[col_Ab]);

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've coded [c](/questions/tagged/c), and I'm sorry to answer and not comment (*not enough points*), but perhaps [**`mysql_fetch_field_direct()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-field-direct.html) might be of help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but maybe this works:

```
SELECT A.a AS 1, A.b AS 2, A.c AS 3 FROM tbl1 A INNER JOIN tbl2 B ON B.id = A.B_id
```

This returns the fields you want with names "1", "2", "3" etcetera. (I am not sure if numeral-only column names are accepted.)